# How to document the method parameter in C#? Exist something like Javadoc?

Tags: c#, .net

I am pretty new in C# (I came from Java)

In Java I often comment my methods using javadoc to document the paramether type and the returned value

Something like

```
/* @param an int
   @param a Rectangle object
   @return void
*/
   public void myMethod(int i, Rectangle rec){
      .............
      .............
   }
```

What is the convention to document these things in C#?

Comment: Yes, you can document your code, at least Visual Studio suports this. Use /// before any class/function/whatever to write a description for the code. More information here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b2s063f7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, look at XML Documentation.

There's a nice page on MSDN all about it - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z04awywx.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "< summary >" tag.

Example from MSDN:

```
/// <summary>DoWork is a method in the TestClass class. 
/// <para>Here's how you could make a second paragraph in a description. <see cref="System.Console.WriteLine(System.String)"/> for information about output statements.</para>
/// <seealso cref="TestClass.Main"/>
/// </summary>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d6dt3kf.aspx

Answer (score 1):

By default visual studio have triple back slash for commenting.When you put that above a function it will shows

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
```

where you can write your comments.

If you want something advanced please get the [Ghostdoc](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/46A20578-F0D5-4B1E-B55D-F001A6345748) from visualstudiogallery.Its a free tool.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert three /// before a method, class, field etc. and write what you want and you can even add examples, exceptions and so on. An example:

```
/// <summary> 
/// A function summary here.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="inParam">An in parameter</param>
```